# Python, math quiz. The questions being asked aren't accepting answers

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, random

I'm trying to write a small python program that asks random math question, but i'm stuck. The random questions being asked aren't accepting the answers even if the answer is correct. Plus it keeps repeating the question. Could you please review my code and let me know what i'm missing?

```
import random
import operator
import time

name = input("Type your name: ") #user name is stored inside name variable
print ("Hi",name,"This math quiz will test your basic math ability.") #Quick 
intro
print ("Please press 'Enter' after every input")
print (" ")

time.sleep(1)

operators = {
           '+': operator.add,
           '-': operator.sub,
           '*': operator.mul,
           '/': operator.truediv
           }

randNum1 = random.randint(9, 999)
randNum2 = random.randint(9, 999)

ops = random.choice(list(operators.keys()))

question = 0
star = 0

def ask_Question():

    que = randNum1, ops, randNum2
    print ("What is", randNum1, ops, randNum2)
    que_ans = int(input(">>>"))

    if que == que_ans:
        print ("Congrats! You earned your first star.")
        print (" ")

    elif que != que_ans:
        print ("Error! Better luck next time.")

def main():

    while question <= 4:
        ask_Question()

main()
```

Comment: Might be better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Code Review is for improving working code. This code doesn't work.

Comment: `que = randNum1, ops, randNum2` is the same as `que = (randNum1, ops, randNum2)`, it creates a tuple, and doesn't calculate anything, contrarily to what you seem to expect.

Comment: Use print() to print out what `que` is (and what the user input is compared to). Then move the random code into the ask question so that you get a new question every time

Comment: Hint: you aren't actually using the *values* in `operators`, otherwise, why not just define `operators = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]`?

Comment: Great read: [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) helps you debug your own programs more easily if followed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the generation of random numbers in the question, and calculate the result of the operation:

```
import random
import operator
import time

name = input("Type your name: ") #user name is stored inside name variable
print ("Hi",name,"This math quiz will test your basic math ability.") #Quick intro
print ("Please press 'Enter' after every input")
print (" ")

time.sleep(1)

operators = {
           '+': operator.add,
           '-': operator.sub,
           '*': operator.mul,
           '/': operator.truediv
           }

randNum1 = random.randint(9, 999)
randNum2 = random.randint(9, 999)

ops = random.choice(list(operators.keys()))

question = 0
star = 0

def ask_Question():

    # You must generate new random numbers and operation in *each* question
    randNum1 = random.randint(9, 999)
    randNum2 = random.randint(9, 999)
    ops = random.choice(list(operators.keys()))

    # operators[ops] is your mathematical function, you must call it 
    # with your numbers as parameters
    que = operators[ops](randNum1, randNum2)

    print ("What is", randNum1, ops, randNum2)
    que_ans = int(input(">>>"))

    if que == que_ans:
        print ("Congrats! You earned your first star.")
        print (" ")

    elif que != que_ans:
        print ("Error! Better luck next time.")

def main():

    while question <= 4:
        ask_Question()

main()
```

Comment: Thank you, this has clarified a lot!

Comment: Quick question, could you please explain to me what  "que = operators[ops](randNum1, randNum2)" is for? I don't quit get it.

Comment: `ops` is your key (for example `+`), so `operators['ops']` would be the function `operator.add`, which takes two parameters and returns their sum. So, you have to call it, as any function, with the parameters between parenthesis. Here, `operators['ops'](p1, p2)` would be the same as `operator.add(p1, p2)`